How to configure the resolver to work with openvpn?
My system is Debian 11, which I haven't changed much concerning the network, except I use OpenVPN to connect to my work. The ip address comes from the router via DHCP, and it sets up two nameservers and a couple of search domains.
When I connect to vpn, an extra nameserver is added at the beginning of /etc/resolv.conf, but that is all, even though the ovpn file specifies a search domain.
What I'd like is for openvpn to completely replace whatever results in /etc/resolv.conf with the setting that I need for work, when it starts up, and then restore the previous settings when I turn off the vpn. I probably have to configure the NIC with a static address, so dhcp doesn't overwrite my settings every time the lease renews, but I can live with that.
I know I can hand-craft things so they work the way I want, but is there a way that is more compatible with resolvconf and network-manager?
